# Flutter, error when building with cmake. Android-16 is not supported for arm64-v8a. Using minimum supported LP64 version 21

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

i'm working in a flutter project and i have this error when try to run the project. The problem seems related to a lib that i'm using ( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport ). I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and i'm using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1. The min sdk android supported by the project is the 21.

---

This is the the exception error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_libserialport:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/libserialport/CMakeLists.txt: -- android-16 is not supported for arm64-v8a. Using minimum supported LP64 version 21.
  -- Android: Targeting API '21' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
  -- Android: Selected unified Clang toolchain
  -- The C compiler identification is Clang 12.0.8
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: /home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
  -- Check for working C compiler: /home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang - broken
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/.cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/.cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      /home/patrick/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake \
        -H/home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/libserialport \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
        -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16 \
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 \
        -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DANDROID_NDK=/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620 \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/patrick/FlutterProjects/rch-ats3-frontend-flutter/build/flutter_libserialport/intermediates/cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/patrick/FlutterProjects/rch-ats3-frontend-flutter/build/flutter_libserialport/intermediates/cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -B/home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/.cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/arm64-v8a \
        -GNinja
    from /home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android
  CMake Error at /home/patrick/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
    The C compiler

      "/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang"

    is not able to compile a simple test program.

    It fails with the following output:

      Change Dir: /home/patrick/.pub-cache/git/flutter_libserialport-849b23ac3228ce46a22b24009becf34765494403/android/.cxx/Debug/r6w2j4vk/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

      Run Build Command(s):/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja cmTC_d3023 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d3023.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
      [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_d3023
      FAILED: cmTC_d3023 
      : && /home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=/home/patrick/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-undefined  -Wl,--gc-sections -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig CMakeFiles/cmTC_d3023.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_d3023  -latomic -lm && :
      ld: error: --fix-cortex-a53-843419 is only supported on AArch64 targets
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried some solution like setting the minimun sdk android on 21 in the lib serialport, like suggested by the error but it doesn't fix it. I'm didn't understand what is the real problem.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?

Comment: @ElihaiDavidVanunu Hi, actually i cannot find a solution.